Read External Storage Permission Request Does Not Appear for Android 13 and later
In a project, I am trying to create a webview application for a site running on Wordpress.
Data such as files and images can be uploaded by accessing the Wordpress Uploader in the application.
When asking for permission to upload files, the application works without any problems on Android 12 and earlier.
But no matter what I do after 13
I cannot request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. The permission request does not appear in the window.
I grant the first permission (camera) and then, without asking for the other permission, I see the toast message on the screen: You have permanently blocked image/file upload.
Additionally, on LogCat, I see this: Read external storage permission granted.
I've been dealing with this problem for hours. I read about the changes in Android 13 and later (main source: Developer Tutorial)
However, I could not solve the problem.
Definitions in AndroidManifest.xml file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>

Code for basic permissions:
//...
private boolean file_permission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
    ){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(permsRequestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("Permissions", "Camera permission granted");
        } else if (grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("Permissions", "Read external storage permission granted");
        }
    }

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can now upload images/files.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // now, user has denied permission (but not permanently!)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your permission is required to upload images/files.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // now, user has denied permission permanently!
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have permanently blocked image/file upload.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}


Indeed READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not available for Android 13+. There are only the tree READ_MEDIA_#. But.... What is your problem?

I see the toast message on the screen: You have permanently blocked image/file upload.???? Who is toasting that? You yourself are doing that. That is a bad problem description. Better tell why you are Toasting that.

What is your problem?

The problem is that it requests camera permission for Android 13 and later. However, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" is not requested and direct permission is denied.
A toast message appears on the phone screen: "You have permanently blocked image/file upload."

That is a nonsense message and also your own message. It tells us nothing. Dont ask for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to begin with. And a CAMERA permission has noting to do with file upload. All is pretty unclear to me. What is it that you want?
